# \multicolumn doesn't center correct when used with overlay

Tags: beamer, multicolumn, overlays

Somehow the center-command of `\multicolumn` doesn't work right, if it's used inside an overlay.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
\only<1>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$1$}}
\only<2>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$2$}}
\only<3>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$3$}}
\only<4>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$4$}}
\only<5>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$5$}}
\only<6>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$6$}}
\only<7>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$7$}}
\only<8>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$8$}}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

standard answer to any question about white space, it is added by ends of lines which act as spaces, you can comment them out with `%` as below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8%
\only<1>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$1$}}%
\only<2>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$2$}}%
\only<3>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$3$}}%
\only<4>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$4$}}%
\only<5>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$5$}}%
\only<6>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$6$}}%
\only<7>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$7$}}%
\only<8>{\\\hline\multicolumn{8}{c}{$8$}}%
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the original, overlay 1 has 1 followed by 8 spaces, and overlay 8 has 8 spaces followed by 8, so the visual appearance is different when centred.

Comment: For other users you should point out, that you added `%`s. I almost didn't see it

Comment: @Ben done  !....

Comment: That's quite surprising. I wouldn't have thought that you can add something in a cell behind a \multicolumn and that spaces matters there. But actually `\multicolumn{8}{c}{$1$} {} {abc} {} {}\\ ` runs without error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's the usual problem, `tabular` does an `\ignorespaces` on the left so any number of spaces at the start get ignored but it just does `\unskip` at the right, so if you manage to get multiple consecutive space tokens, all but the last make space in the output.

Comment: It is more the `abc` that surprised me, I had expected something equivalent to the `! Misplaced \omit.` on the right or at least that the rest is gobbled. Looks as if I never made the syntax error to  forget the & or \\ after a \multicolumn -- something that would be a small wonder.